# Jasmine should ignore post data values

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, http-post, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to test my angular app with Jasmine.
 This is how i call it :

```
$httpBackend
  .expectPOST('http://localhost:3000/booking_requests.json',
    {lat: 58.37, lng: 26.71})
  .respond(201);


sharedProperties.setLatitude(58.37);
sharedProperties.setLongitude(26.71);
scope.submit();
$httpBackend.flush();
```

And here is what i have in the function:

```
$scope.submit = function() {

console.log(sharedProperties.getLatitude());
console.log(sharedProperties.getLongitude());
console.log($scope.formdata.name);


var parameter = JSON.stringify({lng: sharedProperties.getLongitude(), lat: sharedProperties.getLatitude(),
  name: $scope.formdata.name});
console.log(parameter);

$http.post('http://localhost:3000/booking_requests.json',parameter )
  .then(function (response) {
    $scope.sync_notification = response.data.eta;
    $scope.modal.show();
    PusherService.subscribe(response.data.id);
  });
};
```

And the error:

```
   TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'response.data.eta')
```

So i have to make it ignore the json stuff that I'm getting from the post method. Any idea or comment would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response you are returning single value and in actual function you are retrieving the value from object.

You don't need to pass parameter and code in test case should be as below:

```
$httpBackend.expectPOST('http://localhost:3000/booking_requests.json').respond({data:{eta:201,id:456}});
```